# Flow is not working for site guest user in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

I have created a public site and added registration form. Once  i submit the form it will create record in salesforce. Based on the criteria i am sending the email from flows but is not working for site guest user.

Same process is working for salesforce user.

Any idea.

Comment: Is this a lightning community? Public site?

Answer (score 1):

If your org was created after the Winter'22 release, it will not have the 'Run Flow' permission on any Guest User Experience Cloud Profiles.
If your org is old, the 'Run Flow' permission will be removed from the Guest User Profile system permissions in Spring'23.
In order to give a guest user the ability to run a flow, you will have to do the following steps -

1. Go to Setup -> Flows -> Click the dropdown arrow against your flow -> Click 'Edit Access' and enable the 'Override default behavior and restrict access to enabled profiles or permission sets.' checbox -> Click on 'Save'.
2. Navigate to your Guest Profile detail page -> Find and click on the 'Flow Access' setting -> Click 'Edit' -> Add your flow from 'Available Flows' list to the right column.
   Now your guest users with this profile will be able to access and run this flow.
   Documentation - [How Does Flow Security Work?](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_distribute_security.htm&type=5), [Allow Guest Users to Access Flows](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.rss_flow_guestuser.htm&type=5)

Answer (score 0):

Check the guest user profile and see enable as flow run option